# How to call the child constructor function method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I try to call the method( getdetails() method of Teacher ) of child constructor function the parent constructor method is being called . Isn't the child method supposed to shadow the parent method . How to call the child constructor method getDetails()?

```js
let Person = function() { };
Person.prototype.personName = "Smith";
Person.prototype.age = 37;
Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person Name: ${this.personName}. Age is ${this.age}`;
};

let Teacher = function() { };
Teacher.prototype.mainSubject = "Physics";
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}`;
};
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // inheritance

let teacher1 = new Teacher();

console.log(teacher1.getDetails());
```

Comment: You assigned a new object to `Teacher.prototype`, effectively losing whatever it was defined to before that line.

Comment: This coding pattern dates from the period before 2015. Nowadays we use the `class` syntax with `extends`... so much easier to set up inheritance.

Comment: I am still in the learning curve. I used to work with JavaScript for writing small basic scripts . Then I took a break after 2012 . Now I again started learning JS and this time I am taking the OOP way . I will learn the classes in coming times. Hope you will understand. And thanks for your suggestion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign a new object to `Teacher.prototype` therefore losing everything you assigned to it beforehand. You should create the object before everything else.

```js
let Person = function() { };
Person.prototype.personName = "Smith";
Person.prototype.age = 37;
Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person Name: ${this.personName}. Age is ${this.age}`;
};

let Teacher = function() { };
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // inheritance
Teacher.prototype.mainSubject = "Physics";
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}`;
};

let teacher1 = new Teacher();

console.log(teacher1.getDetails());
```

But nowadays you could also use classes instead of functions.

```js
class Person {
  personName = "Smith";
  age = 37;
  
  getDetails() {
    return `Person Name: ${this.personName}. Age is ${this.age}`;
  }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
  mainSubject = "Physics";

  getDetails() {
    return `Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}`;
  }
}

let teacher1 = new Teacher();

console.log(teacher1.getDetails());
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. I am not familiar with classes yet . Will look into it in future . Thanks